# Yii2 display data from phpexcel in view before saving to database

Tags: yii2, phpexcel

I am still on the process of learning Yii 2 framework. I was able to create a form that uploads excel file then save to database using phpexcel. I want to enhance it in a way that the data from the uploaded excel will be displayed on a table in view so the user can check the data if they are the same with the excel file. After checking, the user will have two options whether CANCEL or CONTINUE.

Here is my controller method to read file and save:

```
public function importExcel($model, $readFile, $dir)
{
    try {
        $readFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($readFile);
        $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($readFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($readFile);
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        die('Error reading data from excel file.');
    }

    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
    $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestCol = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

    for($row = 9; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {

        $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A'. $row . ':' . $highestCol . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle('A'. $row . ':' . $highestCol . $row)
            ->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0000');
        //   ->setFormatCode( \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
        if($row == 9) {
            continue;
        }

        $document = new Document();
        $document->type_id = ($rowData[0][0] == 'Ordinance' ? 1 : 2);
        $document->no = $rowData[0][1];
        $document->series = $rowData[0][2];
        $document->title = $rowData[0][3];
        $document->author = $rowData[0][5];
        $document->date_approved = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rowData[0][8].' '.$rowData[0][9].' '.$rowData[0][10]));
        $document->region_c = $model->region_c;
        $document->province_c = $model->province_c;
        $document->citymun_c = $model->citymun_c;
        $document->catParent = 1;
        $document->category_id = 1;
        $document->file_url = $dir . '/unzip/' . $rowData[0][13];
        $document->save();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code and what you have already tried.

Comment: I just want to know if it is possible to load that $rowData in arraydataprovider and pass it to GridView.

Answer (score 0):

If your rowData contain the data  and is an array of the row read form excel you can do this

```
$provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
   'allModels' => $rowData,
  'pagination' => [
    'pageSize' => 10,
  ],
]);


  return $this->render('your:view', [
        'provider'             => $provider,
    ]);
```

and in your grdiView

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $provider,
    ......
```

Comment: How can I get those attributes in 'sort' and columns in gridview? data is from excel and not from database table.

Comment: Well the important part is related at how create a proper ArrayDataProvider.. and this seems right to me the (sort was for eventual sorting) but any way i have update the answer   your answer is just an arrangement of the way i show .. then i think is fair rate my answwer as a right answwr..

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked.

```
try {
        $readFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($readFile);
        $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($readFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($readFile);

    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        die('Error reading data from excel file.');
    }

    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
    $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestCol = $sheet->getHighestColumn();


    for($row = 9; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {

        $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A'. $row . ':' . $highestCol . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle('A'. $row . ':' . $highestCol . $row)
            ->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0000');

        if($row == 9) {
            continue;
        }

        $data[] = array(
            'type' => $rowData[0][0],
            'no' => $rowData[0][1],
            'series' => $rowData[0][2],
            'title' => $rowData[0][3],
            'author' => $rowData[0][5],
            'dateapproved' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rowData[0][8].' '.$rowData[0][9].' '.$rowData[0][10])),
            'file' => $rowData[0][13]
        );

    }

    $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $data,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 10,
        ],
    ]);

    return $this->render('display', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);

}
```